# How do you remove/undo/delete a pending modification on Amazon Aurora RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-aurora

I was pegging the 90 total connections allowed on my Aurora RDS instance, now that I've got a few more heavy duty sites than I had before.  I decided to upgrade the instance and I did so, but put the upgrade as pending until the next maintenance window, without considering adding a read-only replica into the cluster.  I've added the replica and all is well.  I want to cancel that pending upgrade from a db.t2.medium Aurora to a db.r3.large Aurora instance.  I can't find a way to clear out the pending modifications queue.

I have the AWS CLI installed and config'd.  I just can't find documentation on flushing out the pending modifications queue.  Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: This is not possible. You shall open a support case for that.

Comment: The workaround is to postpone it every 7 days for next 7 days :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no documented way to cancel pending modifications.

Note, though, that on an Aurora cluster, the master does not play a role that is as important as you might assume.  It differs from other setups, because your data does not actually live on the master instance -- it lives on the Aurora Cluster Volume, which is not part of any instance -- and replicas have a different relationship to the physical data store than in conventional replication.

> When you create an Amazon Aurora instance, you create a DB cluster. A DB cluster consists of one or more DB instances, and a cluster volume that manages the data for those instances. An Aurora cluster volume is a virtual database storage volume that spans multiple Availability Zones, with each Availability Zone having a copy of the DB cluster data.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Overview.html

So, the nodes don't hold the data -- it's separate, which is one of the powerful features of Aurora's internals.  In fact, Aurora replicas don't have their own copy of the data, so in some strict/literal/pedantic sense, they technically are not even properly *"replicas"* (though that terminology is still used) -- they're just read-only nodes in the cluster.

So, you could probably just do a Reboot with Failover, which would switch the other instance (your new replica) to become the master.  Then create a new replica and destroy the original instance.

Note that if you have replicas in an aurora cluster, you need to be using the [cluster endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Connecting.html) to connect to the writer node or one of the reader nodes, because if your writer ("master") fails, Aurora will usually swap the roles (or possibly *always* swap the roles, though there might be cases where it doesn't).  You might already be doing that.

Comment: Thank you, this is some really good context and a good solution.  I did use the cluster endpoints from the start, even before I added a replica.  Did something right from the start, for once ;)

Comment: Excellent. :) Also, I've added another link to the docs where the Aurora Cluster Volume is explained in a bit more detail.  The console seems to hide some of this from you by creating the cluster and the master at the same time.

Answer (score 24):

As @gileri described, there is now a way to undo a pending modification.

I tested it multiple times with RDS/Aurora instances and it works as expected, even without the `--apply-immediately` parameter (at least for the instance class modifications).

### Full Example

Let's change the instance class for an Aurora instance called `database-2-instance-1` from `db.t3.medium` to `db.r4.large` and undo it again afterwards. None of these commands do impact the availability of the database.

Note: Using `jq` here to only output the important parts.

#### Check instance class

```
$ aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier database-2-instance-1 | jq '.DBInstances[].DBInstanceClass'
"db.t3.medium"
```

#### Validate that there is no pending modification

```
$ aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier database-2-instance-1 | jq '.DBInstances[].PendingModifiedValues'
{}
```

#### Modify instance class

This modification will result in a change of the instance class in the next maintenance window.

```
$ aws rds modify-db-instance --db-instance-identifier database-2-instance-1 --db-instance-class db.r4.large | jq '.DBInstance.PendingModifiedValues'
{
  "DBInstanceClass": "db.r4.large"
}
```

#### Validate again

Just to be sure, check if everything looks as expected.

```
$ aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier database-2-instance-1 | jq '.DBInstances[].PendingModifiedValues'
{
  "DBInstanceClass": "db.r4.large"
}
```

#### Undo modify of instance class

This is the important part which modifies the instance class back to the old value. The documentation describes that a `--apply-immediately` is required, but it turns out that that is not the case. At least in this example.

```
$ aws rds modify-db-instance --db-instance-identifier database-2-instance-1 --db-instance-class db.t3.medium | jq '.DBInstance.PendingModifiedValues'
{}
```

#### Validate the removed pending modification

```
$ aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier database-2-instance-1 | jq '.DBInstances[].PendingModifiedValues'
{}
```

At this point the pending modification is gone.

Comment: This is awesome... I tried and it worked... Thanks for the solution above... Very neat !!!

Comment: It saved me a late night release, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Since [February 2019](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-rds-user-guide/commit/089debd0c38d41835e9ba8cb4abaab511dce19cc#diff-655ea3cbce997ee63c7da8062ee54e1fR24), it is [documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.Modifying.html) that you can cancel such pending modifications.
I have tested this with a pending DB instance class modification.

> If you don't want a pending change to be applied in the next maintenance window, you can modify the DB instance to revert the change using the AWS CLI and specify the --apply-immediately option.

Answer (score 0):

Check your pending modifications:

```
# aws --profile example_profile rds describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier example_globalcluster --region example_region | jq '.DBClusters[].PendingModifiedValues'
{
  "EngineVersion": "12.7"
}
```

Next, stop the global database (which consequently stops the writer node or whatever setup you have) and check again for pending modifications:

```
# aws --profile example_profile rds describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier example_globalcluster --region example_region | jq '.DBClusters[].PendingModifiedValues'
  null
```

When you start the global database again, you'll see that those pending modifications are gone. I managed to solve this issue for two times now.

Answer (score -1):

It is mentioned in the documentation that,

> If you don't want a pending change to be applied in the next maintenance window, you can modify the DB instance to revert the change using the AWS CLI and specify the --apply-immediately option.

However, do note that *--apply-immediately* will result in a reboot of the instance even if you are reverting the changes and rds may be down for about a minute.

Comment: `do note that --apply-immediately will result in a reboot`
That's not true. I tested it multiple times and I cannot confirm a reboot of the instance when reverting changes.